# Different delay time with Handler

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, handler

I have been using 5 Handler tasks in my application with different post delays but all of them are working at a different speed irrespective of the delay time that I have specified, is there a better way to get exact time delay in between of multiple tasks,

Sample Code:

```
H2 = new Handler();
R2 = new Runnable() 
{   @Override
    public void run() 
    {    H2.postDelayed(R2, 100);
         //Do something
    }
};
H2.postDelayed(R2, 0);
```

Task would run in variable time intervals sometimes way more variable.

Comment: Please explain the "delay between the tasks" part. Do you need a certain interval between certain tasks' _start times_ or between the moment one tasks _finishes_ and another starts? Maybe you'd be better off with `Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)`?

Comment: Suppose I am using a handler to update score in a game in every 500ms , so I want to update score in exact 500ms after the time it was last updated, but it is not working that way, indeed sometimes it takes more time and sometimes less.

Comment: Posting to handlers is not meant to be accurate. It simply ques the task and attempts to perform it after the delay. I think you should look into alarm manager.

Comment: As cYrixmorten said, you shouldn't use handlers for exact timing. Alternatively, you can take a look at `ScheduledExecutorService` and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Thanks, it ll be a great help.